# Limiting dynamic dropdown length (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-microservice-5268o

I construct and filter the options of my dropdown using a custom data.

```
const dropdownData = [
  {
    code: "others",
    name: "Others",
    amenity: []
  },
  {
    code: "bed",
    name: "Bed",
    amenity: [
      {
        code: "1",
        name: "Cotton"
      },
      {
        code: "2",
        name: "Down comforter"
      },
      {
        code: "3",
        name: "Custom",
        attributes: [
          {
            code: "1",
            name: "paid"
          },
          {
            code: "2",
            name: "free"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I have 3 dropdown in total, each options data is contrained base on previos selected value, 
I have problem limiting the dropdown to 3 item

To reproduce, select 'Bed -> Custom -> Others -> Bed', you will see new dropdown is added. I'm stuck for hours and need help.

Answer (score 0):

What about always have three dropdowns, but conditional rendering them based on the value of the previous dropdown(s)?
Moreover, this way you can hide a dropdown if it has no possible values.

I've made a little example here -> https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-meadow-vdpyz

I'm not very used to React Hooks, so you can certainly improve the code itself, but the idea I used, I think it suits your needs.